# mock Firebase Initialization in Flutter unit tests

Tags: flutter, firebase, testing, google-analytics, mocking

I use Firebase to log events in my application. In my main function, I call the method *setupFirebaseAnalytics*(), that initializes my Firebase aaplication:

```
   static Future<void> setupFirebaseAnalytics() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
    }
  }
```

I have a simple main **test**. I just call the main function of my application to make sure everything works properly:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  group('Main', () {
    test('setupApplicationContext setup app context successfully', () async {

      await main_app.main(['test']);

      expect(ApplicationContext.envConfig.env, 'test');
      expect(ApplicationContext.envConfig.usernameMaxLength, 4);
    });
  });
}
```

But I get this error

```
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart 210:7  FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore

PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
```

What can I do to test my main function with Firebase? Just the initialization part, **the only thing I do in my app with Firebase is log events**.

I also tried adding *firebase_core_platform_interface* and using the method *setupFirebaseCoreMocks*():

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
setupFirebaseCoreMocks();
```

But I got this error then:

```
[core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
```

Can somebody please help me? This is my first time working with Firebase, and a lot of my tests exploded